# Error: connection not open on send()

Tags: web3js

I'm using "**web3**": "**^1.2.4**"

This is how I connect to **'wss://kovan.infura.io/ws'**

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://kovan.infura.io/ws'))
instance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS);
```

Here I am trying to call PastEvents and for listening

```
const eventOptions = { filter: {}, fromBlock: lastBlock, toBlock: 'latest' };
const events = await instance.getPastEvents('MyEvent', eventOptions);

instance.events.MyEvent(async function (error, result) {
    console.log(result)
});
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Maybe you should provide your Infura-Projcet-ID in that URL (i.e., `wss://kovan.infura.io/yourProjectId/ws`).

Comment: Looks similar to this: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1025

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Turned out the Infura URL I had in my configuration file was invalid. Getting a new endpoint URL from Infura settings solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue with Alchemy on Polygon Mumbai connection (testnet), in a NodeJs app running with PM2 on a virtual machine, starting web3 connection along with the server. It seems that after some time of no use the project starts sending that error.

In Docker projects I haven't face this issue, maybe because the connection is resetting on each request, as container starts.

You could try to make the web3 connection on each request with the strategy that suits you better (Docker microservice or connecting to web3 again on each request).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly right. I had the same issue with a new project I had created on infura. Tried out all possible options but no dice. Then, when I created a new project and entered that url on to the dotenv code. voila... It all worked like a charm!!!